# Is there a way to conditionally JOIN records in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, join, google-sheets-formula

I have a spreadsheet containing a list of municipal offices and which county they are in. I want to join each record associated with a given county into one cell. Kind of like a "JOINIF" function if such a thing existed. I'm stumped on how to do this!

Spreadsheet looks like this:

```
Alameda | Rowan City Council
Alameda | Rowan Mayor
Alameda | Chester School Board
Jones | Fillips School Board
Jones | Smith School Board
Carol | Apple City Council
Carol | Pear City Council
```

At first I thought I could do it by putting this in the cell to the right of a given local office: `=JOIN(", ",IF(A2=A:A,D2:D,""))`, but this obviously just joins ALL records if county = county, which it always will. So I tried reversing the operation: `=IF(A:A=A2,JOIN(",  ",B2:B),"")` but this does much the same. What am I missing here!

**edit** the desired output would look like this:

```
Alameda | Rowan Mayor | Rowan City Council, Rowan Mayor, Chester School Board
Alameda | Chester School Board | Rowan City Council, Rowan Mayor, Chester School Board
Jones | Fillips School Board | Fillips School Board, Smith School Board
Jones | Smith School Board | Fillips School Board, Smith School Board
Carol | Apple City Council | Apple City council, Pear City Council
Carol | Pear City Council | Apple City council, Pear City Council
```

The end goal being that I could then select columns A and C and remove duplicates, leaving me with a list with one row for each county, with column A being the county name and column B being the joined list of local offices in that county.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(
 QUERY(QUERY({ROW(A1:A), A1:A&"×", B1:B&","}, 
 "select max(Col3) where not Col2 starts with '×' 
  group by Col1 pivot Col2"),,9^9)), "×")), ",$", ))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi - I don't understand how this works. Is there a simpler way to do this? Thank you very much for your answer in any case

Comment: This is a common way to unpivot a table, start here this is the core of the formula `ARRAYFORMULA({ROW(A1:A), A1:A&"×", B1:B&","})` lookup those functions in [Google Sheets Help](https://support.google.com/docs#topic=1382883).